# How to define multiple constants in config.js

Tags: javascript, styles, config, constants, pixi.js

I am trying to save some PIXIJS styles in a config.js file, so that I could reuse these style contants in other JavaScript files.
Is it possible to define these multiple constants (fontFamily, fontSize, and fill) together in the config-file?

```
const styleText = new PIXI.TextStyle({
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        fontSize: "20",
        fill: "0xf0000f",
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create js file

```
export default class{
  fontFamily: "Arial",
  fontSize: "20",
  fill: "0xf0000f",
}
```

and in your file use

```
import TextStyle from './path/to/config.js';
const styleText = new PIXI.TextStyle(TextStyle);
```

If you need to have separate values alongside `TextStyles` object add these lines to `config.js`

```
export const lbl1 = 'lbl1';
export const lbl2 = 'lbl2';
```

and change import statement to:

```
import TextStylel, {bl1, lbl2} from './path/to/config.js';
```

Comment: The second constant lbl2 (out of the export default class...) is not recognised. Did I missed something?
`
 export default class{
  fontFamily: "Arial",
  fontSize: "20",
  fill: "0xf0000f",
  },

  lbl1: "lbl1",
  lbl2: "lbl2"    
};
`

Comment: do you need to define it outside the class

Comment: answer changed to include extra constants export, please accept the answer if it was helpful